# How to continuously check if user is at a specific location

Tags: android

i am using google maps API. I have been able to make the user choose a location, the location the user selects will be saved via shared preferences. When the user is at the location it calls a method BUT it only checks if the user is at the location when the user opens the app, AND even when the app is opened and the user travels to the location the app needs to be restarted before the method is called. How can i make it so it continuously checks if the user is at the location even if the app is off.

Here is the code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutoCompleteAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71,136));

    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;
    private static final float METRES_100 = 100;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private static double latit;
    private static double longi;

    private static final LatLng POINTA = new LatLng(latit,longi);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

            if (DataPersistLoc.getLocation(MapsActivity.this).toString() == "") {

            } else {
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(DataPersistLoc.getLocation(MapsActivity.this).toString(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }

            //Initialize Google Play Services
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

                }
            }
            else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }

        }


    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    public void changeType(View view)
    {
        if(mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
        else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    public void onSearch(View view) {

            AutoCompleteTextView location_tf = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(location_tf.getText())) {

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Enter Location",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    latit = address.getLatitude();
                    //saves latitude value to shared preference
                    putDoubleLat(MapsActivity.this);

                    longi = address.getLongitude();
                    //saves latitude value to shared preference
                    putDoubleLong(MapsActivity.this);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                }


            }

    }


    private static SharedPreferences prefs;

    public static long LatPref = 0;
    public static String latPref = "LatPref";

    public static long LongPref = 0;
    public static String longPref = "LongPref";

    public static void putDoubleLat(Context context) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.mobile.counterappmobile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        LatPref = prefs.getLong(latPref, (long) latit);
        prefs.edit().putLong(latPref, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(latit)).commit();

    }

    public static double getDoubleLat(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.mobile.counterappmobile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(latPref, Double.doubleToLongBits(LatPref)));

    }

    public static void putDoubleLong(Context context) {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.mobile.counterappmobile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        LongPref = prefs.getLong(longPref, (long) longi);
        prefs.edit().putLong(longPref, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(longi)).commit();

    }

    public static double getDoubleLong(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.mobile.counterappmobile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(longPref, Double.doubleToLongBits(LongPref)));

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Checks if user is at selected location

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng1);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng1));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mobile.counterappmobile", MODE_PRIVATE);

//Checks if user is at selected location
        Location target = new Location("target");
        for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{POINTA}) {
            target.setLatitude(getDoubleLat(MapsActivity.this));
            target.setLongitude(getDoubleLong(MapsActivity.this));
            if(location.distanceTo(target) < METRES_100) {

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "You Are At This Location",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

            }
        }





    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use the Geofence API?

Comment: ok thanks il try it out

Comment: Could you show me how to use my existing code with geofences, i already know the implementation for the broadcast class but how would i make the saved lat and lng have a geofence.